# groupby and aggregate function not group together ( multiple aggregate number under same group by)

Tags: plsql, group-by, aggregate, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables and I want to group by and get sum of total value

```
select t.originfacilitycode, sum(t.cnt_total),t.soldto,
  case when t.product_id in ('81','36','76','384') then 'Expedited'
   when t.product_id in ('77','82','83','383') then 'Ground'
   when t.product_id in('631') then 'Max' end as parcel_category
    from ops_owner.volume_summary_month t, 
  ops_owner.account_data_pickup p 
 where t.soldto = p.soldto
 and t.product_id in ('81','36','76','384','77','82','83','383','631')
and  t.year = '2017'
and t.month in ('11','12')
   and t.soldto  = '5112087'


group by p.customer_name, t.originfacilitycode,t.soldto,
  case when t.product_id in ('81','36','76','384') then 'Expedited'
   when t.product_id in ('77','82','83','383') then 'Ground'
   when t.product_id in('631') then 'Max' end 

having sum(t.cnt_total) > 60
```

However, the result is not unique by group by.

```
ORIGINFACILITYCODE  SUM(T.CNT_TOTAL)    SOLDTO  PARCEL_CATEGORY
USEWR1                  156864          5112087 Expedited
USEWR1                   78432          5112087 Expedited
```

If I group by ORIGINFACILITYCODE, SOLDTO,PARCEL_CATEGORY why we get multiple return, should be group by, right?

ops_owner.account_data_pickup have duplicate as following, but it should select first one, right?

```
 SOLDTO      PICKUP CUSTOMER_NAME
 5112087    5314711 GOGOTECH
 5112087    5320536 GOGOTECH II, LLC
```

ops_owner.volume_summary_month have sold_to as column

---

update

I pull voluem for same account

```
select t.originfacilitycode, sum(t.cnt_total) 
from ops_owner.volume_summary_month t
where t.soldto = '5112087'
and  t.year = '2017'
and t.month in ('11','12')

group by t.originfacilitycode


ORIGINFACILITYCODE  SUM(T.CNT_TOTAL)
USATL1                   1
USEWR1                  78432
USDFW1                   1
```

Anyone have any clue? why my first query have the first row?

```
ORIGINFACILITYCODE  SUM(T.CNT_TOTAL)    SOLDTO  PARCEL_CATEGORY
USEWR1                  156864          5112087 Expedited
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this query

```
SELECT
    T.originfacilitycode,
    T.cnt_total,
    T.soldto,
    CASE 
        WHEN T.product_id IN ('81','36','76','384') THEN 'Expedited'
        WHEN T.product_id IN ('77','82','83','383') THEN 'Ground'
        WHEN T.product_id IN('631') THEN 'Max'
    END AS parcel_category
FROM
    ops_owner.volume_summary_month T,
    ops_owner.account_data_pickup P 
WHERE
    T.soldto = P.soldto
    AND T.product_id IN ('81','36','76','384','77','82','83','383','631')
    AND T.YEAR = '2017'
    AND T.MONTH IN ('11','12')
    AND T.soldto  = '5112087'
GROUP BY
    P.customer_name,
    T.originfacilitycode,
    T.soldto,
    CASE 
        WHEN T.product_id IN ('81','36','76','384') THEN 'Expedited'
        WHEN T.product_id IN ('77','82','83','383') THEN 'Ground'
        WHEN T.product_id IN('631') THEN 'Max'
    END AS parcel_category
HAVING SUM(T.cnt_total) > 60
```

As you have already commented, you have more than one distinct value at `P.customer_name`, so that is the cause of the duplicated rows.

You must choose the required behaviour that you want here:

- Take the `t.cnt_total` from all the possible values by removing `P.customer_name` from the group by or,
- Define another behaviour when there is more than one value at `P.customer_name`